# Will Apple accept a custom UIAlert?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, appstore-approval

I just read the **iOS Human Interface Guidelines**. In the chapter about **Alerts, Action Sheets, and Modal Views** (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW39)), I found this line :

> The background appearance of an alert
>   is system-defined and cannot be
>   changed.

In my app I created my own UICustomAlert, inheriting from the UIAlertView class, whith following methods :

```
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image andButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    if (self == [super init])
    {
        self.backgroundImage = image;
        self.bigButton = button;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGSize imageSize = self.backgroundImage.size;
    [self.backgroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];
    [self addSubview:bigButton];
}

- (void) show
{
    [super show];

    CGSize imageSize = self.backgroundImage.size;
    self.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
}

- (void)didAddSubview:(UIView *)subview
{
    if ([subview isMemberOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I create my UICustomAlert this way :

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UICustomAlert alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage andButton:bigButton];
[alert show];
```

It permits me to show a UIAlert with a transparent background, and only one image (the `backgroundImage`).

But knowing what is written in [iOS HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW39), do you think Apple will reject the app ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend staying away from the class name of UICustomAlert (if that is the real class name) as the UI prefix may clash with a class in UIKit at some point in the future!

Comment: did you ever submit the app? did it get approved?

Comment: It's currently in validation process. I let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My gut feeling is that you're *probably* safe.  There's nothing stopping you from implementing something like that from scratch.  However I have had an app rejected for not following the HIG (they didn't like the way I worded an error message), so they are more than just "guidelines".